# Button ng-class doesn't apply

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I am trying to create custom pager for `ion-slide-box`. This is [codepen sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbJqpG)

This is my js:

```
$scope.currentSlide = 0;
$scope.pagerClick = function (index) {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
}

$scope.slideChanged = function (index) {
    $scope.currentSlide = index;
}
```

This is html file:

```
<ion-slide-box does-continue=true show-pager=false on-slide-changed="slideChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide class="item-image" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
            <img src='{{images[$index]}}' />
        </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
<div class="page-indicator" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
        <a class="button" href ng-class="{activated: $index == currentSlide}" ng-click="pagerClick($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
</div>
```

Almost all works fine, except one thing. When I click on my pager buttons it doesn't change active button in pager. When I swype slides all buttons change style correctly. I think it may be because of `$index` - I have two such variables. But I can't understand or fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem which was because `activated` is inline class of `button`.
When I push button this class was applying, but when I unpress button Angular delete this class.
I create my class `active-button` and all is now working.

```
<div class="page-indicator" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
        <a class="button" href ng-class="{'active-button': $index == currentSlide}" ng-click="pagerClick($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
```

and css

```
.active-button{
    background-color: #b2b2b2 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```